# webmin dashboard no da opciones o herramientas

Tags: servidor, cookies, cache, display

Hacer unos meses instale en un servidor ubuntu webmin 1.941 y funciono sin problemas hasta ayer. Tras limpiar el navegador (quitar cookies y demas elementos desechables) al entrar al servidor, el dashboard de webmin solo muestra esto tras hacer login

[image: imagen actual]

Se supone que en el lado izquierdo deberia de mostrarme las herramientas de webmin y las mostraba, no estoy seguro de que pude haber cambiado para que dejara de mostrarmelas, el servidor trabaja actualmente sin ssl.

Al ver el codigo de la pagina, donde deberian estar las herramientras solo hay 2

Answer (score 0):

Logre dar con la solucion, por un error se perdieron los privilegios de dicha cuenta de usuario, para corregir esto:
Entrar al archivo: /etc/webmin/webmin.acl y abrirlo para editar
Copiar los privilegios de root y pegarlos en el usuario que no tiene problemas actualmente
Reinicia webmin
Tras esto y podras tener todas las opciones disponibles para trabajar, podras accesar a los usuarios para hacer los ajustes mas especificos usando las herramientas de webmin